# MySql adding a join gives incorrect results

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to join two tables here, so I get the total rows for a particular user based on postStatus. The data is correct without the join, but when I add a join, I get weird results. How is this happening, and what is the right join to use here? I need rows from both tables returned (or null) even if a userId did not exist in one of them.

```
**userData**
"postId"    "userId"    "postStatus"    "checked"   "postTitle"
"1"         "1"         "0"             "0"         "Title 1"
"2"         "1"         "0"             "0"         "Title 2"
"3"         "1"         "0"             "0"         "Title 3"
"4"         "1"         "0"             "0"         "Title 4"
"5"         "1"         "0"             "0"         "Title 5"
"6"         "1"         "1"             "0"         "Title 6"
"7"         "1"         "1"             "0"         "Title 7"
"8"         "1"         "6"             "0"         "Title 8"
"9"         "1"         "5"             "0"         "Title 9"
"10"        "1"         "5"             "0"         "Title 10"
"11"        "2"         "0"             "0"         "Title 1"
"12"        "2"         "0"             "0"         "Title 2"
"13"        "2"         "1"             "0"         "Title 3"

**userDataMod**
"postId"    "userId"    "postStatus"    "checked"   "postTitle"
"1"         "1"         "10"            "0"         "Title 11"
"2"         "1"         "10"            "0"         "Title 12"
"3"         "2"         "0"             "0"         "Title 4"
```

**Sql with join**

```
select
  a.userId,
  sum(a.postStatus = 0) published,
  sum(a.postStatus = 1) inactive,
  sum(a.postStatus = 5) recalled,
  sum(a.postStatus = 6) deleted,
  sum(b.postStatus = 10) unChecked
from userData a join userdatamod b on a.userId = b.userId where a.userId = 1;
// what is the correct join to use here that'll return data (null) from both tables
// even when a userId may not be present in one of them?
```

**Incorrect results (see the results below. those are the correct ones)**

```
"userId"    "published" "inactive"  "recalled"  "deleted"   "unChecked"
"1"         "10"        "4"         "4"         "2"         "20"
```

**Sql without join that gives correct results**

```
select
  a.userId,
  sum(a.postStatus = 0) published,
  sum(a.postStatus = 1) inactive,
  sum(a.postStatus = 5) recalled,
  sum(a.postStatus = 6) deleted

from userData a where a.userId = 1;
```

**Correct results when not using join**

```
"userId"    "published" "inactive"  "recalled"  "deleted"
"1"         "5"         "2"         "2"         "1"
//Note: there are 5 rows with postStatus 0 in userData, and 2 with postStaus = 1 and
1 with postsStaus = 6 and so on for userId = 1
```

What is the right way to get this right?

**Expected result when using join**

```
"userId"    "published" "inactive"  "recalled"  "deleted" "unChecked"
"1"         "5"         "2"         "2"         "1"       "2"
//unChecked = the 2 rows from userDataMod with postStatus = 10 for useId = 1
```

**jens**

```
"postId"    "userId"    "postStatus"    "checked"   "postTitle" "postId"    "userId"    "postStatus"    "checked"   "postTitle"
"1"         "1"         "0"             "0"         "Title 1"   "1"         "1"         "10"            "0"         "Title 1"
"1"         "1"         "0"             "0"         "Title 1"   "2"         "1"         "10"            "0"         "Title 2"
"2"         "1"         "0"             "0"         "Title 2"   "1"         "1"         "10"            "0"         "Title 1"
"2"         "1"         "0"             "0"         "Title 2"   "2"         "1"         "10"            "0"         "Title 2"
"3"         "1"         "0"             "0"         "Title 3"   "1"         "1"         "10"            "0"         "Title 1"
"3"         "1"         "0"             "0"         "Title 3"   "2"         "1"         "10"            "0"         "Title 2"
"4"         "1"         "0"             "0"         "Title 4"   "1"         "1"         "10"            "0"         "Title 1"
"4"         "1"         "0"             "0"         "Title 4"   "2"         "1"         "10"            "0"         "Title 2"
"5"         "1"         "0"             "0"         "Title 5"   "1"         "1"         "10"            "0"         "Title 1"
"5"         "1"         "0"             "0"         "Title 5"   "2"         "1"         "10"            "0"         "Title 2"
"6"         "1"         "1"             "0"         "Title 6"   "1"         "1"         "10"            "0"         "Title 1"
"6"         "1"         "1"             "0"         "Title 6"   "2"         "1"         "10"            "0"         "Title 2"
"7"         "1"         "1"             "0"         "Title 7"   "1"         "1"         "10"            "0"         "Title 1"
"7"         "1"         "1"             "0"         "Title 7"   "2"         "1"         "10"            "0"         "Title 2"
"8"         "1"         "6"             "0"         "Title 8"   "1"         "1"         "10"            "0"         "Title 1"
"8"         "1"         "6"             "0"         "Title 8"   "2"         "1"         "10"            "0"         "Title 2"
"9"         "1"         "5"             "0"         "Title 9"   "1"         "1"         "10"            "0"         "Title 1"
"9"         "1"         "5"             "0"         "Title 9"   "2"         "1"         "10"            "0"         "Title 2"
"10"        "1"         "5"             "0"         "Title 10"  "1"         "1"         "10"            "0"         "Title 1"
"10"        "1"         "5"             "0"         "Title 10"  "2"         "1"         "10"            "0"         "Title 2"
```

**userData**

```
CREATE TABLE `userdata` (
    `postId` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `userId` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `postStatus` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `checked` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `postTitle` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`postId`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=14;
```

**userDataMod**

```
CREATE TABLE `userdatamod` (
    `postId` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `userId` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `postStatus` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `checked` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `postTitle` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`postId`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to yoin with `userid` and `postId`

```
select
  a.userId,
  sum(a.postStatus = 0) published,
  sum(a.postStatus = 1) inactive,
  sum(a.postStatus = 5) recalled,
  sum(a.postStatus = 6) deleted,
  sum(b.postStatus = 10) unChecked
from userData a join userdatamod b on a.userId = b.userId and a.postId=b.postId where a.userId = 1;
```

Comment: postIds are unique and will be different in both tables. Cant join on that.

Comment: @Norman can you show the full output of `select
  * from userData a join userdatamod b on a.userId = b.userId where a.userId = 1;`? And add the ddl of both tables please.

Comment: What do you mean by ddl of both tables?

Comment: @Norman as you can see for every line in  `userData` you got 2 lines in your `join`. Thats why you get a wrong result. Mybe the join of both tables is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
select
  a.userId,
  sum(a.postStatus = 0) published,
  sum(a.postStatus = 1) inactive,
  sum(a.postStatus = 5) recalled,
  sum(a.postStatus = 6) deleted,
  b.unChecked
from userData a left outer join 
    (select userId, sum(poststatus = 10) unChecked
    from userDataMod
    group by userId)
  b on a.userId = b.userId 
 where a.userId = 1;
```

Comment: Is a group by really needed in the second select?

Comment: I would use it to group by the unique user ids, so your derived table (b) has non repeating user ids with aggregated  poststatus (sum in this case)

Comment: Would it be ok to use where userId = 1 in there? Would that solve things?

Comment: You could do that - have to replace the left outer with inner join. But the first approach, I think its a bit more generic ...