# Unknown column when using update and join even when the column exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I use the following sql to update a table called `userStats`, and it runs per user who's `userId` I  supply.

```
update userStats us
join (select
    sum(postStatus = 0) published,
    sum(postStatus = 1) inactive,
    sum(postStatus = 5) recalled,
    sum(postStatus = 6) deleted
from userData where userId = @x) d on d.userId = us.userId 
set
us.published = coalesce(d.published,0),
us.inactive = coalesce(d.inactive,0),
us.recalled = coalesce(d.recalled,0),
us.deleted = coalesce(d.deleted,0),
us.total = coalesce(d.published+d.inactive+d.recalled+d.deleted,0);
```

I keep running into the error `Unknown column 'd.userId' in 'on clause'` even when the column exists in the table. I used to use this very same thing without the error all this time.

Also, concerning the use of `where`, is another `where` needed after the set columns, or will the where inside be sufficient to update only the `userId` I supply. It does update only the `userId` I supply, but I was quite uncomfortable not using one more `where` after the where. Do i need another where outside like I've done before?

```
us.deleted = coalesce(d.deleted,0),
us.total = coalesce(d.published+d.inactive+d.recalled+d.deleted,0) where userId =@x;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table aliased as `d`, does not explicitly select the column `userID` though your `userData` table has the value.

So, You should probably do something like:

```
(select
    userID,  --> This field has to be selected to use in the join condition
    sum(postStatus = 0) published,
    sum(postStatus = 1) inactive,
    sum(postStatus = 5) recalled,
    sum(postStatus = 6) deleted
from userData where userId = @x) d on d.userId = us.userId 
                                         ^
                                         |___ You were getting error here.
```

Comment: It works with that I see. Can you please help with the `where` part, is an additional `where` needed after the set or will the `where` in there do fine.

Comment: I don't think additional where is required. You are joining based on the condition and you need not again add a where clause containing the same condition.

Answer (score 1):

change in your sub query

```
select
    sum(postStatus = 0) published,
    sum(postStatus = 1) inactive,
    sum(postStatus = 5) recalled,
    sum(postStatus = 6) deleted,userId 
from userData where userId = @x
```

Then use `userid` in where clause it works

Comment: Hmm... this same thing used to work just the way it is. Also, is an additional where required again after the set column clauses?

Answer (score 1):

Because you only get one row from the inner query, you don't need a join condition!

```
update userStats us
join (select
    sum(postStatus = 0) published,
    sum(postStatus = 1) inactive,
    sum(postStatus = 5) recalled,
    sum(postStatus = 6) deleted
    from userData where userId = @x) d
set
us.published = coalesce(d.published,0),
us.inactive = coalesce(d.inactive,0),
us.recalled = coalesce(d.recalled,0),
us.deleted = coalesce(d.deleted,0),
us.total = coalesce(d.published+d.inactive+d.recalled+d.deleted,0)
where userid = @x
```

But you do need a where clause in your target table.

This query would perform pretty well too, because both the inner and outer queries use an index-friendly wher clause.

Comment: Yes it is. I used the same thing, but cannot understand why it failed to work since today. It worked perfect even without the userId.

Comment: And btw, any chance you can help here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153430/mysql-adding-a-join-gives-incorrect-results